# ADFS 4.0 (2016) - User prompted for Windows Credentials when Choosing Claims Provider For Authentication

Tags: windows, adfs, claims-based-identity, windows-server-2016

I have an outside org, this org is setup as a claims provider trust within our ADFS.  When a user from this org accesses our IdP initiated sign on page - they hit sign on.  They are then brought to the Home Realm Discovery page where they choose the claims provider.  They are then prompted for Windows Integrated Authentication from our internal AD.  These users do not belog to our Domain.

What I'm trying to figure out is why are they not being re-directed to their IdP.

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand here that the partner organization’s users are being redirected to your organization’s web page because they are accessing a web application or page that is hosted in your environment and their organization has a trust relationship with your organization’s domain. So, through ADFS, your organization domain has a federation with their domain to let them access web page/application hosted in your environment by creating a relying party trust and claims provider trust for accessing that application/web page due to which the people in other organization can see the IDP Initiated sign on page and are able to login to let them access the web application/page.

Since, the resource/page/application they are accessing is hosted in your environment, so they are being redirected to your sign on page. If you want them to not access or login and get claims authentication from your AD, then you have the option of disabling the relying party trust in ADFS Server or may be removing the relying party trust from the ADFS server. Below is the reference command for achieving the same.

‘Remove-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName “Appname”

Please find the below links for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/remove-adfsrelyingpartytrust?view=windowsserver2019-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/disable-adfsrelyingpartytrust?view=windowsserver2019-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/understanding-key-ad-fs-concepts

Thanking you,